# Hibernate 5 change not to use fetch first rows only

Tags: hibernate, oracle11g, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate 5.2 with oracle 11 which does not support fetch first rows only and I need to get back to old style hibernate. 
is there any hibernate configuration to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can force Hibernate to use the Oracle 10g dialect, this way you will get the old limit rule with rownum instead of fetch first.

Looking at the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/pt-BR/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects), you can force the dialect with this property:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Or, if you are using Spring Boot 2 with JPA, you can set this way:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Best regards.

Comment: After more than 3 hours of researches, you are the only one who gave the correct answer. Thanks !