# Hibernate 5: upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-5.x

I am upgrading to Hibernate 5 from 4. I am getting below error while application startup.

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FETCH near line 1

The named queries have "fetch first ? rows only", which was working fine with hibernate 4. Not sure how to solve this. I am using DB2 dialect. Also i have used jpa 2.2.
I found below article but its for oracle.
[Hibernate 5 change not to use fetch first rows only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273992/hibernate-5-change-not-to-use-fetch-first-rows-only)

Thanks,

Comment: I have noticed that the implementation of orderElement() method in org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser has been changed in Hibernate 5. So there is no way to add "fetch first ? rows only" in named query going forward.Just changing the dialect or adding spring boot configuration cannot solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis , i have found that FETCH has not been supported anymore in hibernate 5.